# Installing Wine on Mac OS Catalina. Error: No available formula with the name "wine"

Tags: homebrew, formula, wine, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install Wine on my Mac via Brew. I'm using Catalina and just updated brew, installed XQuartz and have Xcode installed. When I type the command "Brew install wine" it returns the following:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "wine" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

wine was deleted from homebrew/core in commit 82bd38bc:
  wine: delete

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show 82bd38bc^:Formula/wine.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap
```

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/

When I run Brew doctor I get the following:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/tcl.h
  /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

I'm not sure these warnings has something to do with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not a programming question, unless you wish to fix this yourself. Search for answers in a Mac forum instead or file a bugreport if the software doesn't build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to build Wine 64 bit from source on macOS Catalina and successfully run Notepad++ 64 bit on it.

My steps were more or less something like that:

1. Download Wine 4.20 from https://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/4.x/wine-4.20.tar.xz
2. Extract it
3. In terminal go to extracted directory
4. Run: ./configure --enable-win64
5. It showed that it cannot find some library (I do not remember what exactly) so I installed it with macports (sudo port install name_of_missing_package reported by ./configure)
6. After I was able to run ./configure --enable-win64 succesfully without errors in terminal run: make
7. It compiled after more than 30 minutes.
8. I run it with: ./wine start
9. It opened windows console and here I was able to cd to Notepad++ 64 bit directory (downloaded from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.0/npp.7.bin.x64.zip note that newest version did not work and throwed some errors about some dll's)
10. I typed notepad++ to run exe file
11. It showed some errors about freetype fonts so I installed them with macports and I had to copy them from /opt/X11/lib to /usr/local/lib before wine detected them
12. After fixing freetype fonts problem I was able to run notepad++
13. Also you might want to run: sudo spctl --master-disable to disable gatekeeper if you will see some system alerts about loading app from unknown developer.
14. Also note that instead of ./wine start you can run ./wine explorer for graphical file manager instead of console

Those steps might not be exactly precise, as I'm not sure if I did not miss something but hope it will help someone.

Also note that obviously wine on macOS Catalina will be able to run only some 64 bit windows apps and all 32 bit windows app will not work. I also tested it with IrfanView 64 bit (https://www.fosshub.com/IrfanView.html?dwl=iview453_x64_setup.exe) and it also works fine.

In case you wanted to get wine working for purpose of running 32 bit games then unfortunately it will not work with wine but you can try with virtualbox. You can check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AO8dF0vviQ for some performance improvements tips.

Comment: So you didn't require any dependency libs like OpenSSL?

Comment: There's some more stuff in the comments [at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376427)

Comment: please update the link to new version of wine - 6

Answer (score 4):

Wine hast been removed from homebrew due to the incompatibility to Macos Catalina

https://discourse.brew.sh/t/issue-with-wine/6188/3

Comment: how do I install in on an older version of osx

Answer (score 3):

## How to install wine on Mac OS Catalina with brew

- install homebrew with

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

- install xquartz to install wine using brew

```
 brew cask install xquartz
```

- install wine using brew

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/wine-devel
```

- run wine and check the version

```
wine64 --version
```

Comment: this one does not work anymore, shows a warning message: “Wine Devel” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Comment: that should be not an issue because you can "allow" the execution, you have to go to the path binary file and manually open it with the mouse and "allow" the execution

Comment: Works awesomely Oct 2022

Answer (score 3):

Try using `wine64` to run your `.exe` files after installing wine. The manuals and references don't seem to mention this explicitly.

### More Info

I followed the guidance in the [wine manual](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS) to install using home-brew. After install, I got an error when trying to test the installation like it says in the [quickstart](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Quick_start).

**Install wine-stable using homebrew**

```
  brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
  brew install --cask --no-quarantine wine-stable
```

**After install, test by opening notepad**

```
  wine notepad
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: wine
```

While uninstalling wine, I noticed one of the linked libraries was called `wine64`. I immediately reinstalled and tried again using wine64 as the call, as I am using wine on an M1 Mac. This was **successful**!

You can also use `winehelp` to get access to more commands that will work with 64bit processor.

Comment: And where to find notepad ? :D

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/46556#issuecomment-559938873 you can do `brew cask install wine-stable` on newer version of OS X.  And works with recent versions of homebrew since the source version was moved :(

Comment: Doesn't work for me (macOS Catalina 10.15.2). The error launching `wine` is `bad CPU type in executable: wine`

Comment: @fferri Run `wine64` instead

Answer (score 0):

As of Wine 5.0 there is no 32bit support on mac in the official version, but you are able to achieve it via the

### Unofficial Wineskin Winery

You can download it from github releases [here](https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer/releases). And then create a Wineskin with WS11WineCX[64/32]bit19.0.[0/1]. All WS11 versions support Catalina. To use it you also need to turn off the no32exec boot argument. You theoretically can do it by typing:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="no32exec=0"
```

into the Terminal while you're logged in but it didn't work out for me, so if you'll have the same problem, reboot into the Recovery mode, in the menubar pick Utilities -> Terminal and type just:

```
nvram boot-args="no32exec=0"
```

(without sudo).

### Example

To be more exact, to install eg. Steam 32bit, you would:

1. Install the [Unofficiall Wineskin Winery from the provided link](https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer/releases)
2. Turn on the 32bit execution boot argument by going into Recovery Mode and entering `nvram boot-args="no32exec=0"` into the terminal
3. Open Wineskin, click the '+' sign and scroll down to find the WS11WineCX64bit19.0.1 (the newest version with 64 and 32 bit support, at the time of writing)
4. Click update/install under the Wrapper Version.
5. Click Create New Blank Wrapper, name it and click through installation of mono and gecko.
6. Launch the Wrapper App from Finder. Click Install Software, choose setup executable, and proceed through installation. Then pick the executable from a menu. (In case of steam, Steam.exe)

**Note:** If you get the "No windows app to open the file"(Like I did) error, click advanced -> configuration and set the Windows EXE to the path to the installer. Then find the place that it has installed in and set that as Windows EXE. Then you can run by clicking Test Run.

7. Enjoy your windows app, as an .app file!

*Hope I helped!*